# Can't figure out how to create a select statement from this scenario?

Tags: sql

Can you please help formulate a select statement from the scenario below?

```
column1    column2      column3    column4           column5         column6
a          b             c          alt1              alt2           alt3
aa         bb            cc         alt1              alt2
aaa        bbb           ccc        alt1
```

if column6 !=Null then results should give me 3 rows of data

```
abcalt3
abcalt2
abcalt1
```

if column6 = Null and column5 !=Null then results should give me 2 rows of data

```
aabbccalt2
aabbccalt1
```

if column6 = Null and column5 = Null and column4 != Null then results should give me 1 row of data

```
aaabbbcccalt1
```

Comment: Could you add some information about what you have tried yourself already, and your findings, please?

Comment: "Can't figure out how to create a select statement from this scenario?" -- You could start by figuring out what DBMS you really use and only tag that...

Comment: column6 has 2 null values, and 1 non-null. What's the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with UNION ALL with separate select statement for different conditions as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=968017f8292e0fe9d7e1abf9f1981a56)

```
SELECT column1+column2+column3+column4 
FROM your_table where column6 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT column1+column2+column3+column5
FROM your_table where column6 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT column1+column2+column3+column6 
FROM your_table where column6 is not null

UNION ALL

SELECT column1+column2+column3+column4 
FROM your_table where column6 is null AND column5 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT column1+column2+column3+column5
FROM your_table where column6 is null AND column5 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT column1+column2+column3+column4 
FROM your_table where column6 is null AND column5 IS NULL AND column4 IS NOT NULL
```